# How can I send url where I use sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session, sessionid

I use sessions in the products site. My problem is how can I send the single products datasheet site's url.

In the product datasheet site, I fill up the sessions when I click on a product's image in the index site:

```
<?php session_start(); include "connection.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE img = '".$_COOKIE['image_src']."'");

while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $_SESSION['fid'] = $f['id']; //product id
    $_SESSION['fimg'] = $f['image']; //product image
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $f['name']; //product name
    $_SESSION['fdecription'] = $f['decription']; //product description
    $_SESSION['fcategory'] = $f['category']; //product category
}
?>
```

Than the same site I write out the sessions (the product infos):

e.g:

```
<?php session_start(); print ($_SESSION[fname]);
echo "<img src='".$_SESSION['fimg']."' height='350' width='250'>";?>
```

But this way always the last clicked products infos will be in the sessions.
And I can't open more than one product's datasheet at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem:

Firstly I have to call the page this way: `index.php?image_src=XY`
Then I need to use `$_GET` insted of `$_COOKIE`.
Finally with this way the sessions are unnecessary.

```
<?php include "connection.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE img = '".$_GET['image_src']."'");

while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $fid = $f['id']; //product id
    $fimg = $f['image']; //product image
    $fname = $f['name']; //product name
    $fdecription = $f['decription']; //product description
    $fcategory = $f['category']; //product category
}
?>
```

And I can write out the datas:

```
<?php echo "<img src='".$fimg."' height='350' width='250'>";
echo "$fdecription";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I never noticed this! You should remove this "answer" and append this code to the original question

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create another "level" to your session array:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE img = '".$_COOKIE['image_src']."'");

# Create a counter variable
$counter = 0;

while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $_SESSION[$counter]['fid']         = $f['id']; //product id
    $_SESSION[$counter]['fimg']        = $f['image']; //product image
    $_SESSION[$counter]['fname']       = $f['name']; //product name
    $_SESSION[$counter]['fdecription'] = $f['decription']; //product description
    $_SESSION[$counter]['fcategory']   = $f['category']; //product category

    # Increment the counter
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

Then on the page which you want to view the images, just loop that array:

```
<?php

for( $i=0; $i<count($_SESSION); $i++ )
{
    ...
    echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION[$i]["fimg"].'">';
    ...
}

?>
```

[Multi-dimensional Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)

[PHP Docs - Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: I would like to view only one image, that product's image which I clicked on.

Comment: And in the browser appears just the ...://.../productdata.php
How can I earn that appears for example the product's name or id : ...://.../productdata/product1 without creating php files for every single product?